# Can I disable @file:Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING") from entire Android project?

Tags: android-studio

I don't want this suggestion. I can do by top of file, but there are more than 200 file, is there any way to disable this particular warning from entire project?

Warning: `Name shadowed`

Code:

```
@file:Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Warning of Variable Shadowing in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102976/remove-warning-of-variable-shadowing-in-kotlin)

Comment: @laalto Noo that is not answer of my question. Because I already read that answer, but it is not a solution. I need fix for project level and specifically mention in my question as well.

Comment: To me it looks like the same question

Comment: @laalto If question is similar, then what about answer? Answer is not accurate